# Where could I get mono's TPL.Dataflow?

Tags: mono, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I am working with mono-3.0.10 on a Macbook. In the mono 3.0 release note, Tpl.Dataflow is mentioned, and I also noticed that the source code of Tpl.Dataflow is there in mono's github repo master branch.

But I couldn't find it in my local mono install.

```
logan@Logans-MBA  /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework 
{13-06-04 3:47:48} $ find . -name "*.Dataflow.*"
./Versions/3.0.10/lib/mono/4.5/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll
logan@Logans-MBA  /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework 
{13-06-04 3:59:55} $ file ./Versions/3.0.10/lib/mono/4.5/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll
./Versions/3.0.10/lib/mono/4.5/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll: broken symbolic link to ../gac/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll
```

I have tried reinstall the mono from installer, but no luck.

Then, I tried the dlls downloaded from nuget, the following errors comes:

```
/Users/logan/Workspace/Camp/Dragon/ClientEventHandlerDemos/DataflowBlockClientEventHandler.cs(11,13): error CS0012: The type `System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly `System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
/Users/logan/Workspace/Camp/Dragon/ClientEventHandlerDemos/DataflowBlockClientEventHandler.cs(11,34): error CS0012: The type `System.Action`1<TInput>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly `System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

There are 3 editions from nuget, net45, netcore45 and portable-net45. I tried them all, but still no luck.

So, where could I find the right update to date Tpl.Dataflow works with mono?

Comment: The version on NuGet is the version from MS, I'm not surprised it doesn't work on mono. The issue with the symbolic link looks like something is wrong with the installation, but I have no idea where to start looking to fix that.